# Bash: pip: command not found for install (SYMFONY3)

Tags: windows-7, symfony-3.3

When I try this command in CLI(Symfony 3)

```
pip install --upgrade httpie
```

I get this error:

> bash: pip: command not found

What do I have to do to get rid of this error?

Comment: I improved some formatting and added an answerable question.

Comment: **thanks  @zx485**